# C# Xamarin button ICommand or Click event

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am learning Xamarin and I found two options for buttons:

1. Command
2. Click

What is better to use and when?

The docs only provide an example for Command, but it doesn't explain why Command is used and not Click.

```
<Button Text="Back"
                Command="{Binding DeleteCharCommand}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                BorderWidth="0" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Command interface is preferable over a Click because if you register Click handlers in your ViewModel, then it becomes tied and dependent of that View, which goes totally against the [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) architectural pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The whole philosophy of the MVVM pattern is that your View is detached from anything (often people refer that UX Designers could be working on the layout of the view while developers are working on the "back-end" without interfering with each other.) See : [Separation of Concerns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/11/14/mvvm-technical-description.aspx)

So basically, it's considered a bad practice creating Click's events for controls but (My personal experience working with XAML) there's nothing that really stops you from doing that. Just keep in mind that it's bad design and that you should be using Commands.

There's a great explanation in the Xamarin Docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/#Commanding_with_ViewModels)

Answer (score 2):

Commands provide two benefits over click EventHandlers:

1. They are not bound to a caller. One command can be executed from different views, types, etc. While a click event handler sits in a very specific code-behind file.
2. Commands provide functionality to enable/disable UI based on the `CanExecute` method.

If you don't need the `CanExecute` feature, you can easily go with event handlers.
MVVM architectures promote the use of commands, because you can bind directly to the commands, which prevents codebehind.

I personally only add commands, when the can execute feature is relevant, because having to setup all the command properties adds more code than just adding some event handlers.

When using `x:Bind` (aka compiled bindings) you can also bind to methods directly, so you don't even have the eventhandler any more.

Comment: Is it possible to have both a click event and a command? In my case, I want my button to display a 'pressed' effect whilst it executes a command.